# Defining private properties in Wix Installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

First, let me define what I mean by saying private property. Normally, properties can be set using scripting such as follows:

```
<Property Id="CHECKREGISTRY">
      <RegistrySearch Id="CheckRegistryKey"
                      Root="HKLM"
                      Key="SOFTWARE\Foo"
                      Name="Bar"
                      Type="raw" />
</Property>
<Condition Message="You don't have the required permission to install this tool.">
   <![CDATA[Installed OR CHECKREGISTRY]]>
</Condition>
```

But the problem is that you can bypass this check by simply running a script like this:

```
msiexec.exe /i FooInstaller.msi /quiet CHECKREGISTRY="#1"
```

and that is against the very first idea that you should have the registry key to be able to do what you want to do.

As you see, a private property -- if exists -- would prevent this and allow being able to set only from within the MSI installer itself.

I was thinking to go to `CustomAction` route, but for a very simple thing, it is overly complicated. Is there any simple solution to this problem, or how can we define private properties in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a private property by naming it with a lowercase letter. Public properties are all-uppercase.

However, you can't use `AppSearch` to set private properties.

Remember that MSI databases can be inspected so there's no real security. Best you can get is to use custom actions to obfuscate.

Comment: Thanks. At least, it will prevent them from being a part of other scripts and installers. I am glad that we have this option. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem is now: "Error CNDL0012: The Property/@Id attribute's value, 'checkRegistry', cannot contain lowercase characters.  Since this is a search property, it must also be a public property.  This means the Property/@Id value must be completely uppercase. (32)
"

Comment: Right. `However, you can't use AppSearch to set private properties.`

Comment: I didn't know you meant RegistrySearch by saying AppSearch. I am still relatively new to MSI installer universe. Thanks though.

Comment: `AppSearch` is the standard action for all MSI searches.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, a property consisting only of uppercase letters is public. To make it private use some lowercase characters.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371245(v=vs.85).aspx

If you are worried about a public property being set in the command line, just explicitly set it to an empty value before AppSearch.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your source. +1